# Añadir texto a cada linea del Fichero

Tags: java, archivo

Necesito leer un fichero calificaciones.txt y añadir a cada linea de ese fichero una palabra. El problema es que consigo añadirlo al final del mismo pero no a cada linea. Además a veces de forma errática.

**Contenido del fichero:**

- Castillo Perez Jose-8-
- Ruiz Merlo Enrique-6-
- Cantarero Ruiz Juan-4-
- Castillo Ruiz Carlos-10-

**public static void calificarAlumnos(){**

```
    //Leemos Fichero
    try{

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(RUTA));
        BufferedWriter bufferW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(RUTA, true));

        String linea;
        while((linea = buffer.readLine()) != null){

                if(linea.contains("10") || linea.contains("9")){
                    bufferW.write("SOBRESALIENTE");
                }else if(linea.contains("8") || linea.contains("7")){
                    bufferW.write("NOTABLE");       
                }else if(linea.contains("6")){
                    bufferW.write(linea + "BIEN");   
                }else if(linea.contains("5")){
                    bufferW.write(linea + "APROBADO");     
                }else{
                    bufferW.write(linea + "SUSPENSO");  
                }

    }

        bufferW.close();
        buffer.close();

    }catch (EOFException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ficheros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ficheros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Ficheros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } }
```

**Resultado Esperado:**

- Castillo Perez Jose-8-NOTABLE
- Ruiz Merlo Enrique-6-BIEN
- Cantarero Ruiz Juan-4-SUSPENSO
- Castillo Ruiz Carlos-10-SOBRESALIENTE

**Resultados Obtenido**

- Castillo Perez Jose-8-
- Ruiz Merlo Enrique-6-
- Cantarero Ruiz Juan-4-
- Castillo Ruiz Carlos-10-NOTABLERuiz Merlo Enrique-6-BIENCantarero
  Ruiz Juan-4-SUSPENSOSOBRESALIENTE

Comment: Algo un pooc loco si alguien ocupa: Existe una herramienta llamada awk que permite solucionar este tipo de problemas (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796313/awk-if-condition-is-met-add-string-to-these-lines), y existe una implementación en Java que se podría agregar como librería (http://jawk.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Javadoc de FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)):

> public FileWriter(File file,
>             boolean append)
>             throws IOException
>
> Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Con el `true` en el constructor, le dices que escriba al final.

En todo caso, leer y escribir del mismo fichero a la vez puede tener consecuencias negativas (en el supuesto de que el Sistema Operativo te permita hacerlo, para empezar).

Incluso cuando se pueda, cada stream abierto tendrá su propio estado, posiblemente buffers, etc. Puede pasar cualquier cosa.

Para hacer esto, recomiendo una de las dos opciones:

- Leer todo el fichero al principio, p.ej., guardando una lista de `String`, cerrarlo y abrirlo de nuevo para escribir los datos.
- Escribir en un fichero temporal y, una vez cerrados ambos ficheros, copiar el fichero temporal sobre el fichero original.

Comment: Si, usaba el true para que no borrara nada de lo que había, ya que si usaba false escribía al inicio del fichero y por tanto se cargaba la info que había. Gracias por la respuesta ya lo he solucionado moviendo ambos procesos lectura/escritura a dos métodos diferentes. Lectura me almacena en una lista los alumnos y escritura los modifica y los vuelve a escribir, sobrescribiendo lo que hubiera.

Answer (score 1):

Por si a alguien le puede interesar la solución ha sido:

Primero **leer el fichero** y almacenar los datos en un `ArrayList`.

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(RUTA));

String linea;
ArrayList<String> alumnos = new ArrayList();

while ((linea = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
    alumnos.add(linea);
}
buffer.close();
```

Por ultimo modificar los datos y **escribirlos en el fichero**.

```
        BufferedWriter bufferW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(RUTA, false));

        for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.size(); i++) {
            if (alumnos.get(i).contains("10") || alumnos.get(i).contains("9")) {
                bufferW.write(alumnos.get(i) + "SOBRESALIENTE");
            } else if (alumnos.get(i).contains("8") || alumnos.get(i).contains("7")) {
                bufferW.write(alumnos.get(i) + "NOTABLE");
            } else if (alumnos.get(i).contains("6")) {
                bufferW.write(alumnos.get(i) + "BIEN");
            } else if (alumnos.get(i).contains("5")) {
                bufferW.write(alumnos.get(i) + "APROBADO");
            } else {
                bufferW.write(alumnos.get(i) + "SUSPENSO");
            }
            bufferW.newLine();
        }

        bufferW.close();
```